# function to search and replace multiple words - necessary to goto-line 1 every time?

Tags: search, replace

This is a very rudimentary question, but I have a document in which I need to replace many different words fairly frequently, so I created a function that goes like this:

```
(defun chikan ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-line 1)
  (replace-string "ichi" "one")
  (goto-line 1)
  (replace-string "ni" "two")
)
```

The actual function is a lot longer (the words in the example are just placeholders). I figured out that I had to stick the `(goto-line 1)` before every `(replace-string)` because it was going through the whole doc on the first sweep and then stopping, and not replacing words later in the list.

My rudimentary question: is there another way to make it search and replace all words in a document?

Comment: I have written up an answer that uses a different approach, but wanted to mention that the widely accepted approach to programmatically go to the beginning of the buffer is with `(goto-char (point-min))` and the end of the buffer is with `(goto-char (point-max))`.

Comment: Thanks! I don’t know if I should ask here or elsewhere, but is there an easy way to pass a dictionary (like in Python) to this function, which it could just loop through, substituting variables with the dictionary members?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an `alist`, which is similar to a Python data structure.  A handful of forum participants have posted hybrid Python / Lisp solutions to a variety of issues ranging from reading email to calendar management, but those types of answers will only help a finite number of future Google / forum searchers looking for solutions to similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `replace-regexp`, which contains optional arguments for `START` and `END`?  To control lazy highlighting while the search is being performed, the variable `query-replace-lazy-highlight` can be customized or let-bound to the desired setting; e.g., `nil` for no lazy highlighting.  See also the variables `lazy-highlight-initial-delay` and `lazy-highlight-interval`.

```lisp
(defun chikan ()
"Doc-string."
(interactive)
  (replace-regexp "\\<ichi\\>" "one" nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (replace-regexp "\\<ni\\>" "two" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

The following example uses an `alist` (similar to the data structure of a Python dictionary), which is an application requested by the O.P. in a follow-up comment underneath the question hereinabove:

```lisp
(defun chikan ()
"Doc-string."
(interactive)
  (let ((alist '(("ichi" . "one")
                 ("ni" . "two"))))
    (dolist (elt alist)
      (replace-regexp (concat "\\<" (car elt) "\\>")
                      (cdr elt)
                      nil
                      (point-min)
                      (point-max)))))
```

Rather than using word boundary delimiters in the first argument as depicted in this example, see the optional argument in `replace-regexp` for DELIMITED which contains a doc-string entry as follows:  "*Third arg DELIMITED (prefix arg if interactive), if non-nil, means replace only matches surrounded by word boundaries.  A negative prefix arg means replace backward.*"

For an answer that deals with regexp matches that excludes surrounding word constituents, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941448/2112489 , the text of which is copied hereinbelow for convenience:

The regexp `\<foo\>` or `\bfoo\b` matches `foo` only when it's not preceded or followed by a word constituent character ([syntax code](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Syntax.html) `w`, usually alphanumerics, so it matches in `foo_bar` but not in `foo1`).

Since Emacs 22, the regexp [**`\_<foo_bar\_>`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) matches `foo_bar` only when it's not preceded or followed by a symbol constituent character. A symbol constituent is either a word constituent or a character with syntax `_`. Most programming mode define `_` to be a symbol constituent.